# How can right click in Finder without using the trackpad or a mouse?

Tags: keyboard, finder

My goal is to select a file in Finder and get to the "open with" menu without having to leave the keyboard.

Comment: you can find some note here: http://superuser.com/questions/105373/how-to-open-context-menu-in-macos-finder-with-keyboard

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ctrl+F2 to move the focus to the menu bar and then use the arrows to go to the Open With menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Not without 3rd party. Check out [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/).

Comment: I've been using a keyboard shortcut to simulate 'ctrl+click', the problem is that only works if my mouse is on top of the file

Answer (score 0):

I second the Quicksilver answer in the superuser thread referred to above — If you're a keyboard person you have to have this (or similar apps like Launchbar or Alfred).